# Find nearest element, not closest

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had an impression that `closest()` will give me nearest matching element as it suggest but I was wrong, it will give me nearest ancestor, so does `parents()`. So how can I get nearest element?

e.g. I have 2 `div`s as below

```
<div id="clickme">
    Click me
</div>
<div class="findme" style="display:none">
    Find me
</div>
```

what to do if I want to get `.findme` with reference with `#clickme`.

Can I do something like `$('#click').helpfullFunctionThatGivesNearestElement('.findme')`?

Or do I need to scan entire DOM like `$('findme')`? but there can be 100s of `.findme` then how will I find nearest to specific element?

**Update**

`.findme` can be anywhere in DOM.

Comment: Do you have any relationship between above tow elements? Or they can be placed anywhere

Comment: @Satpal anywhere. Only one that is closest should be picked.

Comment: When you say _nearest_ you mean before of after `clickme` or the both ? and if you've one before and one after which of them should be picked?

Comment: Assuming they are siblings you could use `$('#clickme').nextAll('.findme:first')`, however the answer completely depends on the structure of your HTML

Comment: @Imad you need to do recursive dom traversing which can be very inefficient..

Comment: @I.G.Pascual thanks, I think the same. Would contonue this way till someone answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how recursively traversing the DOM looks like.

I've implemented the function **`$.fn.nearest`**, as OP asumes to use jQuery, so it can be called with `$('clickme').nearest('.findme');`

The method will find multiple elements** (if they share the same *distance* from the starting node) by looking towards and backwards in every direction (parent, children, next and prev) by recursively searching through the nearest checked elements. It also avoids checking an element over and over again (i.e. the parent of multiple children is only checked once).

If you don't need a particular direction to be checked, i.e. `children` or `prev` you can just comment that part.

Some checks are made before the recursion is done. When the selector is not found in the DOM an empty jQuery element is returned, also when there is only one element found that found element is returned.

I haven't tested it's efficiency with a large HTML, it all depends on *how far* the desired element is located, and that is directly related to the complexity of the HTML structure. But for sure it is exponential, something close to O(n³) or O(n⁴).

Give it a try.

```js
$.fn.nearest = function(selector) {
  var allFound = $(selector);

  if (!allFound.length) // selector not found in the dom
    return $([]);

  if (allFound.length == 1) // found one elem only
    return allFound;
  else
    return nearestRec($(this), selector);

  function nearestRec(elems, selector) {
    if (elems.length == 0)
      return this;

    var selector = selector;
    var newList = [],
      found = $([]);

    $(elems).each(function(i, e) {
      var options = e[1] || {};
      e = $($(e)[0]);

      // children
      if (!options.ignoreChildren)
        updateFound(e.children(), selector, newList, found, {
          ignoreParent: true
        });

      // next
      if (!options.ignoreNext)
        updateFound(e.next(), selector, newList, found, {
          ignoreParent: true,
          ignorePrev: true
        });

      // prev
      if (!options.ignorePrev)
        updateFound(e.prev(), selector, newList, found, {
          ignoreParent: true,
          ignoreNext: true
        });

      // parent
      if (!options.ignoreParent)
        updateFound(e.parent(), selector, newList, found, {
          ignoreChildren: true
        });
    });

    return found.length && found || nearestRec(newList, selector);

    function updateFound(e, selector, newList, found, options) {
      e.each(function() {
        var el = $(this);
        if (el.is(selector)) {
          found.push(el);
          return;
        }

        newList.push([el, options]);
      });
    }
  }
};


$(function() {
  // multiple elems found, traverse dom
  $(".clickme").nearest(".findme").each(function() {
    $(this).addClass("found");
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  padding: 5px 3px 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 3px;
}
.found {
  background-color: red;
}
.clickme {
  background-color: #37a;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="findme">
  findme
  <div class="findme">
    findme
    <div>
      &nbsp;
      <div>
        &nbsp;
      </div>
      <div>
        &nbsp;
      </div>
      <div class="clickme">
        clickme
        <div>
          &nbsp;
        </div>
        <div>
          &nbsp;
          <div class="findme">
            findme
            <div class="findme">
              findme
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="findme">
            findme
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        &nbsp;
        <div class="findme">
          findme
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="findme">
        findme
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="findme">
      findme
      <div>
        &nbsp;
      </div>
      <div>
        &nbsp;
      </div>
      <div class="findme">
        findme
        <div class="findme">
          findme
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        &nbsp;
      </div>
      <div class="findme">
        findme
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**jquery plugin:**

```
(function( $ ){
    $.fn.nextElementInDom = function(selector, options) {
        var defaults = { stopAt : 'body' };
        options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        var parent = $(this).parent();
        var found = parent.find(selector + ":first");

        switch(true){
            case (found.length > 0):
                return found;
            case (parent.length === 0 || parent.is(options.stopAt)):
                return $([]);
            default:
                return parent.nextElementInDom(selector);
        }
    };
})( jQuery );
```

**Usage:**

```
 $('#clickme').nextElementInDom('.findme');
```

Comment: This code will find a 3rd level matching child before a second level matching parent

Comment: easy... https://jsfiddle.net/8twn11tv/1/, even more.. it will find a nth level child before the second parent

Comment: yeah, it will give the next element wherever it is but not in before, so it breaks the nearest clause.

Comment: If we add hasClass check in parent inside the plugin, and if it has then returning the parent, will it work?

Comment: It doesn't need to work only for that specific case... remember that _.findme can be anywhere in DOM._, and no.. it won't work, it will still return the nth level child ;)

Answer (score -1):

Instead of traversing the entire DOM tree, you can try to locate an element with reference to its enclosing parent.

```
<div>
<div id="clickme" onclick="$(this).parent().find('.findme').show();">
    Click me
</div>
<div class="findme" style="display:none">
    Find me
</div>
</div>
```

This will however work only if the element that you search has a same ancestral parent.

Comment: This won't work if the second parent is the _nearest_ matching element, as stated: _.findme can be anywhere in DOM._